# Change content and style when element is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and JS and I'm trying to create a list with events. Each event should show a name and expanded to show more info when clicked.  I have managed to render three elements and make something happen when each one is clicked but I don't think this is right. Also I can't seem to change the name of the element when it is pressed. The code below always shows the same name no matter what. When the element is "inactive" it should show only the name and time for an event. When it is clicked, it should show everything. With the code below I expect it to toggle between YES and NO as I am unable to reach the event between the classes for some reason.  I am sure most of my code here is wrong:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import CalendarEvent from "./CalendarEvent";

export default class Calendar extends React.Component {
  event1 = new CalendarEvent(
    1,
    new Date("December 20, 1995 10:15:00"),
    new Date("December 20, 1995 12:15:00"),
    "Code",
    "Learn React by fooling around",
    "Company1",
    "LA"
  );
  event2 = new CalendarEvent(
    2,
    new Date("December 25, 1995 12:15:00"),
    new Date("December 25, 1995 15:45:00"),
    "Coffee",
    "Drink coffee",
    "Company1",
    "LA"
  );
  event3 = new CalendarEvent(
    3,
    new Date("December 25, 1995 16:15:00"),
    new Date("December 25, 1995 18:30:00"),
    "Travel",
    "Take the bus home",
    "Streets",
    "LA"
  );
  eventArray = [this.event1, this.event2, this.event3];

  state = {
    activeIndex: null
  };

  handleClick = index => this.setState({ activeIndex: index });
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyClickable
          name={
            this.event1.topic +
            " " +
            this.event1.startTime.getHours() +
            ":" +
            this.event1.startTime.getMinutes()
          }
          index={0}
          isActive={this.state.activeIndex === 0}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
        <MyClickable
          name="EntryB"
          index={1}
          isActive={this.state.activeIndex === 1}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
        <MyClickable
          name="EntryC"
          index={2}
          isActive={this.state.activeIndex === 2}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MyClickable extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => this.props.onClick(this.props.index);

  render() {
    return (
      <li
        type="li"
        className={this.props.isActive ? "EventUl" : "DailyDate"}
        name={this.props.isActive ? "YES" : "NO"} // This has no effect
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        {this.props.name}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class CalendarEvent {
  constructor(
    id,
    startTime,
    endTime,
    topic,
    description,
    organizer,
    eventLocation
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.topic = topic;
    this.description = description;
    this.organizer = organizer;
    this.eventLocation = eventLocation;
  }

  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
  getConcatedString() {
    return (
      this.startTime.getHours() +
      ":" +
      this.startTime.getMinutes() +
      "-" +
      this.endTime.getHours() +
      ":" +
      this.endTime.getMinutes() +
      "|" +
      this.topic +
      "|" +
      this.description +
      "|" +
      this.organizer +
      "|" +
      this.eventLocation
    );
  }

  getStartTime() {
    return this.startTime;
  }

  getEndTime() {
    return this.endTime;
  }

  getTopic() {
    return this.topic;
  }

  getDescription() {
    return this.description;
  }

  getOrganizer() {
    return this.organizer;
  }

  getEventLocation() {
    return this.eventLocation;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow kille! Could you include your `CalendarEvent` as well? Even better, you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Comment: Sure, I will add the CalendarEvent. I want to provide all the code but the project is so large, I  will try.

Comment: To me it looks like [your code is already working](https://codesandbox.io/s/moz9lpxmxx).

Answer (score 0):

In MyClickable component name is the prop you're passing but
li is a html element and the name is an attribute which is changing to YES or NO in the dev tools Elements tab along with the class name
you can take a look at it

[image]

If you want to change the actual name value of the prop
you need to change it in the parent and by passing a function reference to MyClickable Component, similar to handleClick